# Very basic N1QL grouping data operation

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

So I am learning N1QL in order to write some queries to see usage data, and I am trying to look at data that looks like the following:

```
   "data": {
      "datapoints": [
        {
          "point1": "data 1",
          "point2": "data 2",
          "point3": "data 3"
        },
        {
          "point1": "more data 1",
          "point2": "more data 2",
          "point3": "more data 3"
        }
     ]
    }
```

If I select like this:

SELECT data.datapoints[*].point1, data.datapoints[*].point2 FROM datatable

I get the data back grouped by the name of the column, like this:

```
[
  {
    "point1": [
        "data 1",
        "more data 1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "point2": [
        "data 2",
        "more data 2"
    ]
  },
]
```

Is it possible to set up the query so that it returns data grouped by object, as opposed to grouped by the data point(s), but just with the fields I want?  I would like to look at by document, instead of by data point across documents, just with a subset of the data points in the documents.  Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I notice if I set up my query like this:

```
SELECT data.datapoints[0].point1, data.datapoints[0].point2 FROM datatable
```

My data is formatted properly, like so:

```
  "datapoints": [
    {
      "point1": "data 1",
      "point2": "data 2",
    }
   ]
```

but of course only the first datapoints record is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELECT ud AS datapoints FROM datatable d UNNEST d.datapoints AS ud;

UNNEST works same as JOIN. UNNEST works on arrays.
datatable d UNNEST d.datapoints AS ud makes Cartesian JOIN of d and each element of  d.datapoints. Finally we project ud.

Checkout UNNEST Clause for details.

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/from.html

Comment: I'm not sure why but that does exactly what I want it to.  Thanks!